# How to print star pattern using Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Im trying to figure out to print star pattern using Dart language which implementing logic code. The existing code I use as indent so that the star have some space. Is this the right method to do so?

[image]

```
void main(){

    for(int i = 0 ; i< 7; i++){
      var stars='';
        for(int j = (7-i); j > 1 ;j--) {
           stars += ' ';
        }
      for(int j = 0; j <= i ;j++){
           stars += '* ';
    }
      print(stars);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my answer write in dartpad, change `starWidth` to adjust star size.

Idea is get string of the **star** and it padding per row then printing its.

*EDIT: Updated description comment for each functional*

```dart
void main() {
  const starWidth = 7;
  
  // return `*` or `space` if even/odd
  starGenerator(i) => i % 2 == 0 ? "*" : " ";

  // just return a string full of `space`
  printPad(w) => " " * w;
  
  // cause we need `space` between `*`, length is `w * 2 - 1`, 
  // return a string build of star
  printStars(int w) => List.generate(w * 2 - 1, starGenerator).join('');

  for (int row = 1; row <= starWidth; row++) {
    // cause our width with space is `starWidth * 2`, 
    // padding left is `padding = (our width with space - star with with space) / 2`, 
    // but we only need print left side (/2) so the math is simple 
    // `padding = width - star with without space`
    var padding = starWidth - row;
    print("$row:" + printPad(padding) + printStars(row));
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
void main(){

    for(int i = 0 ; i< 7; i++){
      var stars='';
        for(int j = (7-i); j > 1 ;j--) {
           stars += ' ';
        }
      for(int j = 0; j <= i ;j++){
           stars += '* ';
    }
      print(stars);
}
}
```

Comment: Is this an answer or the code you have tried and didn't work?